# expand search and return all objects Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Currently in my `ModelViewSet` I'm returning all contacts for today, additionally I'm checking if the `query_params` on the request for searching/filtering is available and not empty, In that case I'm not adding "today" to the `queryset` so that will perform search on the entire `queryset`.

Problem is that I need to extend search so the user can see other users contacts, but only when he search for them, default view should not be changing if you are not searching, so how can I extend my current filter and return all objects in search.

My current view:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, filters

from cms.restapi.pagination import StandardResultsOffsetPagination
from cms_sales.models import LeadContact
from cms_sales.restapi.permissions.lead_contact_permissions import LeadContactPermissions
from cms_sales.restapi.serializers.lead_contact_serializer import LeadContactSerializer


class LeadContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = LeadContact.objects.none()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.has_perm('cms_sales.can_view_full_lead_contact_list'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.all()
        elif user.has_perm('cms_sales.can_view_lead_contact'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.filter(account_handler=user)

        filter_date = self.request.query_params.get('filter_date', None)
        search_params = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)

        if filter_date is not None and (search_params is None or len(search_params) == 0):
            queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date=filter_date)

        return queryset

    serializer_class = LeadContactSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)

    filter_fields = ('account_handler',)

    ordering_fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_handler__first_name', 'account_handler__last_name',
        'sub_organization_name', 'organization_name', 'next_action_date', 'serial_number',
        'status_text')

    search_fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_handler__first_name', 'account_handler__last_name',
        'sub_organization_name', 'organization_name', 'next_action_date', 'serial_number',
        'status_text')

    pagination_class = StandardResultsOffsetPagination

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, LeadContactPermissions]
```

Current Serializer:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

from cms_sales.models import LeadContact


class AccountHandlerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class LeadContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account_handler = AccountHandlerSerializer()
    next_action_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format=settings.CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT_NO_TIME)
    absolute_url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url')

    class Meta:
        model = LeadContact
        fields = (
            'pk', 'organization_name', 'sub_organization_name', 'serial_number', 'account_handler', 'status_text',
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'next_action_date', 'absolute_url', 'status_display_class'
        )
        depth = 1
```

Current Model:

```
class LeadContact(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    sub_organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    account_handler = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='handling_leads', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    next_action_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name="Next action on lead")
    status_text = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30)
```

Comment: where are you adding "today" to the queryset? and what is "today"?

Comment: I have a datetime field in my `controller` and I'm sending date parameter and filtering against it in `filter_date` so I can show my contact by `next_action_date` for today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the code to check permissions below the code where you check for search param so that you are applying the user filter after checking for search_params

```
def get_queryset(self):

    queryset = LeadContact.objects.all()

    if (not user.has_perm('cms_sales.can_view_full_lead_contact_list') and
        not user.has_parm('cms_sales.can_view_lead_contact')):
        return queryset.none()

    user = self.request.user

    filter_date = self.request.query_params.get('filter_date', None)
    search_params = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)

    if filter_date is not None and (search_params is None or len(search_params) == 0):
        queryset = queryset.filter(next_action_date=filter_date)


    if user.has_perm('cms_sales.can_view_lead_contact') and not search_params:
        queryset = queryset.filter(account_handler=user)


    return queryset
```